# Best practice for creating SQL Server databases for a data warehouse

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-warehouse

I'm about to create 2 new SQL Server databases for our data warehouse:

1. **Datawarehouse** - where the data is stored
2. **Datawarehouse_Stage** - where the ETL is done

I'm expecting both databases to be able 30GB and grow about 5GB per year. They probably will not get bigger than 80GB (when we'll start to archive).

I'm trying to decide what settings I should use when creating these databases:

- what should the initial size be?
- ...and should I increase the database size straight after creating it?
- what should the auto-growth settings be?

I'm after any best practice advice on creating those databases.

UPDATE: the reason I suggest increasing the database size straight after creating it, because you can't shrink a database to less than its initial size.

Comment: AH - take sql server out. Ttable design for a data warehouse has very little to do with a product. Plus, 30gb and 5gb per year are not a data warehouse. THat is a homesystem. I just now do a data warehouse with a data load of 150gb. PER DAY. Archiving 2 years.

Comment: @TomTom A Data Warehouse is not defined by the amount of data it holds.

Comment: Ah, it is, partially. Design decisions that makes sense from a perforamnce point of view are useless if you deal with "toy amuonts of data". The whole star denormalized data  schema is there for performance reasons. Usless for small amounts of data.

Comment: A DW is an integrated, subject-oriented, nonvolatile database. Size has nothing to do with it. A denormalised star schema isn't a defining property of a DW either. Enterprise DWs are frequently designed to be in Normal Form. BCNF / 5NF is good practice for any warehouse and normalisation usually becomes more important as the DW gets larger.

Comment: Never assume that database growth is linear.

Comment: such great question, no real answers given

Answer (score 0):

> •what should the initial size be?

45gb? 30 + 3 years grow, especially given that this fits on a LOW END CHEAP SSD DISC ;) Sizing is not an issue if your smallest SSD is 64GB.

> ...and should I increase the database size straight after creating it?

That would sort of be stupid, or? I mean, why create a db with a small size jsut to resize IMMEDIEATLEY after, instead of putting the right size into the script in the first step.

> what should the auto-growth settings be?

This is not a data warehouse question. NO AUTOGROW. Autogrow fragemnts your discs.

Make sure you format the discs according to best practices (64kb node size, aligned partitions).

Comment: The reason I said that I should create a small initial size and then increase it, is because you can't shrink the db files less than the initial size. So, if the initial size is large, you are stuck with that.

Comment: And 30gb is large for you? I mean, really, given todays technology that is tiny.

Comment: @TomTom Well, if 30gb is tiny, that's fine. But I would still like to create this database in the best way. (My mistake to include the size and get into this my database is bigger than yours discussion)

Comment: Craig, If you think it will be a requirement to shrink the database smaller than 30gb (presumably after deleting some data?) then that may be a reason to create it with a smaller initial size. However, that seems like an unlikely requirement in most circumstances. Shrinking is very rarely required in any database because data tends to grow rather than shrink. In some circumstances it may be useful to shrink when creating a test / dev environment perhaps but then 30GB is pretty small already. So I guess the question remains: why might you want to shrink the database in future?

Comment: @dportas Thanks for the comment. I might want to shrink the database if I need a copy to develop / test on. I could restore on my dev / test server, shrink the database and then work on that.

Comment: Not with data loaded. And if you dont ahve data,. make a small new database and deploy schema and reload there.